# Regular Expression to split by comma + ignores comma within double quotes. VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to parse csv file with VB.NET.

csv files contains value like 0,"1,2,3",4 which splits in 5 instead of 3. There are many examples with other languages in Stockoverflow but I can't implement it in VB.NET.
Here is my code so far but it doesn't work...

```
 Dim t As String() = Regex.Split(str(i), ",(?=([^\""]*\""[^\""]*\"")*[^\""]*$)")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your csv is well-formed (ie no `"` besides those used to delimit string fields, or besides ones escaped like `\"`), you can split on a comma that's followed by an **even number of non-escaped "-marks**. (If you're inside a set of "" there's only an odd number left in the line).

Your regex you've tried looks like you're almost there.

The following looks for a comma followed by an even number of any sort of quote marks:

```
,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

To modify it to look for an even number of *non-escaped* quote marks (assuming quote marks are escaped with backslash like `\"`), I replace each `[^"]` with `([^"\\]|\\.)`. This means "match a character that isn't a " and isn't a blackslash, OR match a backslash and the character immediately following it".

```
,(?=(([^"\\]|\\.)*"([^"\\]|\\.)*")*([^"\\]|\\.)*$)
```

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?2vu9e).
(The reason the backslash is doubled is I want to match a literal backslash).

Now to get it into vb.net you just need to double all your quote marks:

```
splitRegex = ",(?=(([^""\\]|\\.)*""([^""\\]|\\.)*"")*([^""\\]|\\.)*$)"
```

Comment: Hmm, the regex works in the link I posted on the input you gave in your question, so perhaps it is another problem. Are you sure `str(i)` is what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a regular expression, try using the TextFieldParser class for reading .csv files.  It handles your situation exactly.

[TextFieldParserClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

Especially look at the HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes property.

Example:

Note:  I used a string instead of a file, but the result would be the same.

```
    Dim theString As String = "1,""2,3,4"",5"

    Using rdr As New StringReader(theString)
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(rdr)
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
            parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
            Dim fields() As String = parser.ReadFields()

            For i As Integer = 0 To fields.Length - 1
                Console.WriteLine("Field {0}: {1}", i, fields(i))
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
```

Output:

```
Field 0: 1
Field 1: 2,3,4
Field 2: 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code but I'm getting an error. "Line 1 cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters."

Comment: The code worked just as written for me.  Did you change it?  How is your code different?

Comment: This is something I have been looking for for 2 years. Not sure why it never came up before. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, and no need for any external libraries. Working on VS2019. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it with regex VB.NET in the following way:

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

The positive lookahead ((?= ... )) ensures that there is an even number of quotes ahead of the comma to split on (i.e. either they occur in pairs, or there are none).

[^"]* matches non-quote characters.

Given below is a VB.NET example to apply the regex.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim theString As String = "1,""2,3,4"",5"
        Dim theStringArray As String() = Regex.Split(theString, ",(?=(?:[^""\\]*""[^""\\]*"")*[^""\\]*$)")
        For i As Integer = 0 To theStringArray.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine("theStringArray {0}: {1}", i, theStringArray(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

'Output:
'theStringArray 0: 1
'theStringArray 1: "2,3,4"
'theStringArray 2: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for parsing a Shipping Notice .csv file we receive.  Thanks for keeping this solution here.

This is my version of the code:

```
Try
Using rdr As New IO.StringReader(Row.FlatFile)
    Using parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(rdr)
        parser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
        Dim fields() As String = parser.ReadFields()

        Row.Account = fields(0).ToString().Trim()
        Row.AccountName = fields.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim()
        Row.Status = fields.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim()
        Row.PONumber = fields.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim()
        Row.ErrorMessage = ""

    End Using
End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    Row.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
End Try
```